# convertion of .mp4 file to .3gp in windowsphone 8 using c#.net

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-capture

Using capturesource I got the video in isolated storage, But I need to upload that video to server,
whenever I try to send the video, The size is huge so I need to compress(convert) the video from MP4 to 3GP

The default message screen of windows phone shows  "processing video" whenever I send a video message through attachment,and it convert .mp4 video to .3gp.

I tried a lot of research to achieve the conversion from MP4 to 3GP please help me

The code is

```
CaptureSource captureSource      = new CaptureSource();

 private string isoVideoFileName  = "CameraMovie.mp4";

 private FileSink fileSink;

 VideoCaptureDevice webcam = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultVideoCaptureDevice();

 AudioCaptureDevice audio = CaptureDeviceConfiguration.GetDefaultAudioCaptureDevice();

 captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice = webcam;
 captureSource.AudioCaptureDevice = audio;

 fileSink = new FileSink();

 fileSink.CaptureSource = captureSource;
 fileSink.IsolatedStorageFileName = isoVideoFileName;
 captureSource.Start();
```

I tried to change the resolution of `VideoCaptureDevice` but it not helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for you, you can upgrade your app to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight (you'll need to download Update 2 for Visual Studio 2013 and put the developer preview on your developer device(s)). The conversion itself is straightforward - I had no issues with a very complex WP 8.0 app (although backup your app first!)

Once that's done you can then access the `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` library. This will allow you to change to more resolutions than are available using `VideoCaptureDevice`. For example you can create a profile that will record video to QVGA like this:

```
MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Qvga);
```

Which will give you a resolution of 320 x 240 and a file size of ~20MB for 4 mins of video. Still not ideal from my purposes either, but a big improvement. `MediaEncodingProfile` also has methods like `MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv()` and `MediaEncodingProfile.CreateAvi()` but I've not been able to get these to work yet (see my question here: [MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv gives "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content." error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121125/mediaencodingprofile-createwmv-gives-no-suitable-transform-was-found-to-encode)).

The tutorial I used to get video recording using MediaCapture can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642092.aspx

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no public API that allows you to convert from MP4 to 3GP.

One option would be to port FFmpeg to Windows Phone but currently, if anyone has done it, its not publicly available.